# How can i use if statement on for loop output from the excel datas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new in Pandas, I want to use if conditional operator to the printed loop output from excel

```
for i in range(0,10,3):
    line = df.loc[i].to_numpy()
    print(line[0], line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4],line[5],line[6],Line[7],Line[8])
```

Output:

```
Year N1 N2 N3 N4 N5 N6 N7 N8 
 77  13 23 26 31 35 43 58 88
 80  3  13 16 23 24 35 78 99
 83  2  29 10 14 22 44 66 90
```

For example if Year has value of 58 then only to print the number

Answer (score 1):

The idea of working with pandas is not to use for loops to go through the rows, and neither to convert the rows to NumPy arrays. Rather, use pandas functionalities to do so. In this case, we can get only the row where Year is 58 by doing:

```
df[df.Year == 58]
```

or

```
df.query('Year == 58')
```

If Year was part of the index, you should instead do:

```
df.loc[58]
```

That will return the row with the Year equal to what you want. To print it you have 2 possibilities: "print(df)" or "display(df)". I recommend "display" because if you are working in a Notebook the format will be prettier.